# converting .csv string values to double

Tags: java, csv

I am having difficulties reading string number values from a .csv file and converting them into double values. Here is the code:

```
String filename = "/home/mahmoud/Desktop/CSV/remake1.csv";

    BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    int val;

try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
        String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        val = Integer.parseInt(country[4]);

                    System.out.println(val);

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Done");
}
```

When I compile the program I get the following error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.55"

Here is the content of the .csv file:

2012-12-03,5.63,6.57,5.32,6.55,5816300,6.55

2012-11-01,4.66,5.68,4.37,5.59,5752000,5.59

2012-10-01,5.27,5.40,4.42,4.67,5958000,4.67

2012-09-04,5.91,6.56,5.21,5.26,5930600,5.26

any suggestion on how to fix that problem?
Thank You

Comment: If it's a `float`, why are you using `Integer.parseInt()`? Declare `float val;`, and use `Float.parseFloat()` instead.

Comment: Or better, `Double.parseDouble()`

Comment: True, but given the numbers in the example, I figured a `float` would be sufficient.

Comment: The question says "converting them into double values".

Comment: You are only handling a subset of the CSV file syntax. Your code will break if there are ever double-quote delimited strings with commas in them. You probably don't need to care about this since you only need to handle one very specific CSV file, but using a library like Apache Commons CSV, Open CSV, or Super CSV would avoid such issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number format shows that it's not an integer, but a double.

So you should declare `val` as a double:

```
double val;
```

And use the following line to parse :

```
val = Double.parseDouble(country[4]);
```

Comment: The question says "converting them into double values", not float.

Comment: Edited to double. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Your title says you want *double*, yet you parse your String using `Integer.parseInt()`, which will parse Integers. Use `Double.parseDouble()` instead to get a *double* value.